# How do I keep the data when I change routes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a JavaScript function (ring buffer) that outputs an array to a modal, but the data is not saved if I change routes. How can I save the data if I change routes? Do I have to use Vuex?

I was thinking of another approach and using props, but I'm not sure how exactly to pass the data from the routes.

I'm unfamiliar with how props work, but I'd have to do something along the lines of adding this `props: ["historyProp"]` to my `Countrylist` component, and ID-ing the modal in order to pass the props to the home page?

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-babbage-olcw6)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap `<router-view>` with [Vue's built-in `<keep-alive>` component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive) to keep the component instance alive between route changes:

```html
// App.vue
<template>
  ...
  <keep-alive> 
    <router-view></router-view>
  </keep-alive>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/keep-component-instance-between-route-changes-7bxvn?file=/src/App.vue:126-194)

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain the data in VueJS in two main ways:

1. Using the local component data property
2. Using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

When you are working on an application which is having fewer components and your application is quite small then you can go for the local data property of the component for maintaining the state. In this case, when you want to pass the data between the component then you can use props and events to share the data between components.

If your application is big and you need to share a lot of data between components, so using the local data property will need many operations to share the data, so in this case, you can use Vuex which will help you to maintain a global store which can be used by all the components to access the data.